# Why Azure Web App not starting when I add maxAllowedContentLength in web.config?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, web-config

I'm developing ASP.NET 7 WebApi app which is hosted on Azure Web App. I need to transfer large files. Many resources show that I need to add node in web.config, but when I add, my azure web app won't start.

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                        stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
            <security>
                <requestFiltering>
                    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647 " />
                </requestFiltering>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 46edd0a7-6184-47ed-a0e9-d3be7fee8b41-->
```

And this message is shown when I try to open web app:

[image: page error]

As in title: Why it's not working? Do I missed some step?

My .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` file ?

Comment: `And this message is shown when I try to open web app`. Can you share the message.

Comment: I noticed that you have a whitespace at the end of  `maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647 "` - it should deleted so that you have a valid integer number in this attribute.

Comment: @AnnaGevel shame on me... You're right, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As AnnaGevel mentioned, I had typo in my web.config file. That was the culprit.

Thanks everyone who triad to help.